# Can I skip calling the setLayout() method if I pass "self" in the parameter list to initialize a QLayout?

Tags: python, pyqt5

Consider the following piece of layout code:

```
def __init__(self, parent=None):
    super().__init__(parent)
    self.layout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self)
```

Will the above code have the same effect as the below code?

```
def __init__(self, parent=None):
    super().__init__(parent)
    self.layout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
    self.setLayout(self.layout)
```

In other words, if I call `QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self)`, is that equivalent to calling `self.setLayout`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, those two code snippets have equivalent functionality, as explained in the [`setLayout()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#setLayout) documentation:

> An alternative to calling this function is to pass this widget to the layout's constructor.

Note that your code has another lurking bug: `layout()` is a Qt *property*, so you should not overwrite it using `self.layout = ...`, as the existing function will return the *current* layout anyway.